# InstaBot API Follow not Working

Tags: python, instagram

I am using InstaBot Python API its working fine for Instagram Likes,  But if i set only follow then nothing is happened. I tried a lot to fix this but did not get Proper solution. Could any one please let me know where i am worng in the code ? Here is  my code :

```
bot = InstaBot(
            login               =   'xyz',
            password            =   'xyz',
            like_per_day        =   0,
            comments_per_day    =   0,
            tag_list            =   '',
            tag_blacklist       =   ['rain', 'thunderstorm'],
            user_blacklist      =   {},
            max_like_for_one_tag=   50,
            follow_per_day      =   10,
            follow_time         =   1 * 60,
            unfollow_per_day    =   0,
            unfollow_break_min  =   120,
            unfollow_break_max  =   180,
            log_mod             =   0,
            proxy               =   '',

            comment_list=[
                            ["photo", "picture", "pic", "shot", "snapshot"],
                        ],
            # Use unwanted_username_list to block usernames containing a string
            ## Will do partial matches; i.e. 'mozart' will block 'legend_mozart'
            ### 'free_followers' will be blocked because it contains 'free'

            unwanted_username_list=[
                'second', 'stuff', 'art', 'sex', 'food', 'blog',
            ],

            unfollow_whitelist=['example_user_1', 'example_user_2']
        )
```

Please Help me to Fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your tag list is empty. You need to set some tags for the bot to search so it can follow the people. I'd also recommend updating your default values so it's a bit easier for you to comprehend the configurations. You can build this up over time when you decide to use different features.

[I'd recommend reading over the README.md for instructions on how to use the bot](https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py)

(assuming this is the one you're using - the configurations look familiar to me)

```
bot = InstaBot(
            login               =   'xyz',
            password            =   'xyz',
            like_per_day        =   0,
            comments_per_day    =   0,
            tag_list            =   ['sun', 'sea', 'water'],
            tag_blacklist       =   [],
            user_blacklist      =   {},
            max_like_for_one_tag=   50,
            follow_per_day      =   10,
            follow_time         =   1 * 60,
            unfollow_per_day    =   0,
            unfollow_break_min  =   120,
            unfollow_break_max  =   180,
            log_mod             =   0,
            proxy               =   '',

            comment_list=[],
            unwanted_username_list=[],
            unfollow_whitelist=[]
        )
```

Comment: hi Thanks for reply :

i have added the lag list  in my code : e.g 
tag_list            =   ['sun', 'sea', 'water'],

but still nothing is happened :(